# adding custom panels to an Applet with a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, applet, cardlayout

I cannot figure out the JavaDocs for the CardLayout. I have an Applet, and from this Applet I have 5 classes I created that extend JPanel. Inside these classes all that has been done so far is the design (some GUI components). Now I want to link all these classes together through the Applet so one panel is viewed at a time (CardLayout). Thus, I will have the capability from my Applet to use CardLayout's next method to view the next panel. Here is my code:

```
setLayout(new CardLayout());

add(mainView);                //mainView, managerView, searchView, storesView and hoursView
add(managerView);             //   are initialized
add(searchView);
add(storesView);
add(hoursView);
```

Here is my event handling code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    CardLayout cl;                        //CardLayout object to manipulate the next page

    cl = (CardLayout)(this.getLayout());

    if(e.getSource() == mainView.getManagerButton())
    {
        cl.next(this);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == mainView.getSearchButton())
    {
        cl.next(this);              //if the user hits the searchButton I want to link to panel
        cl.next(this);              //   searchView. Is that correct?
    }
}
```

With this code, I get an IllegalArgumentException

Someone please point out my error! Also I have provided some comments for questions in the code.
As Always, Thanks!

Comment: Which line shows the error? What is the exact error message? Have you looked at the CardLayout tutorial that I linked to in your other question?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't use any constraints to identify each card when you added the panels to your card layout. Then you can jump directly to the specific card.

See [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example.

Comment: I dont understand the constraint in the link. In the tutorial they set initialize "cards" as a JPanel with a CardLayout. Next they add two other JPanels card1 and card2 to cards with a static final string as the second parameter. I dont understand why they add that static string. Also, the compiler gives me this message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string

Comment: The constraint is simply a String identifier for the card. Its easier to use a static variable for the string value so you don't have to type the string value in  two places. It avoids typing mistakes. If you get an error message then do what the messages says. Use a String as the constraint.

Comment: *"I dont understand the constraint in the link."*  When you are advised something that you do not understand, it is best to ask then, on the thread where advised.  People around here love answering questions, and are mostly happy to expand.

Answer (score 0):

To make it even more clear, some snippets literally copied from the link provided by @camickr

Creation of the panel

```
//Create the panel that contains the "cards".
cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);
```

where `BUTTONPANEL` and `TEXTPANEL` are Strings. Switching between the different panels is done by calling

```
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
cl.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem());
```

where the `evt.getItem()` will be equal to `BUTTONPANEL` or `TEXTPANEL`

Comment: Hey, I still dont get it. I tried an simplified example with two classes that extend JPanel and then I add them to the applet with the constrait "Next" which is the text on my Buttons. Why does that not work? I got an Illegal argument exception with the message cannot convert from borderlayout to cardlayout

Comment: `public void init()  {  
        setLayout(new CardLayout());  
        
        titleView = new titlePanel();  
        titleView.next.addActionListener(this);  
        contentView = new contentPanel();  
        contentView.next.addActionListener(this);  
        
        add(titleView, "Next");  
        add(contentView, "Next");  
        
    }  
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
    {  
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(this.getLayout());  
        
        cl.show(this, "Next");  
    }`

Comment: You can't post code in a comment. Instead edit your original question, and post the code there.  Also, please don't double post here and in other forums.

Comment: Also, please accept some of the answers to this and previous questions of yours here.

Comment: And where in that piece of formatting-lacking piece of code do I find those two different Strings used in the card layout as shown in the links and the code snippets posted here ? How can that card layout know what to show if you always use the same constraint ?

Comment: Hey everyone! Thanks with all the help, my applet is turning out really well! How do I edit my original post? I have one new smaller question and then I should be done!

Comment: You might want to start [accepting some answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) before posting new questions, as mentioned before

Comment: What does accepting answers mean? I'm really new to this posting hahaa

Comment: Click on the link which brings you directly to the relevant part of the FAQ.